# Creating MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, aqua-data-studio

I am using Aqua Data Studio 20.6 to create a MySQL stored procedure. The following is my procedure, I have named it `sp_GetObjIDByProType`:

```
( IN prono char(15), IN imgtype char(8), OUT objid bigint )
BEGIN
    SELECT ObjectID INTO objid FROM images WHERE ProNumber = prono AND DocType = imgtype LIMIT 20;
END
```

When I try to create the stored procedure, I get this error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN imgtype char(8) )
( OUT objid bigint )
BEGIN
    SELECT ObjectID INTO objid F' at line 3
```

However, it appears as if creating the task was actually successfully
([sp_GetObjIDByProType appears under 'Procedures'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkVh4.png)). I can view and alter this created stored procedure in another window ([resulting stored procedure in 'Alter' window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7T9m.png)). Does this mean that creation of the stored procedure was actually successful, or is there something wrong with what I did?

Comment: Pay attention: the code itself and its citate in the error message differs.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for your response. I noticed that, do you know why there was a difference? I tried creating some other stored procedures and got no errors like this. Is it safe to ignore the first error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your procedure was created. However, the `LIMIT 20` in the query does not make sense. You are returning the selected `ObjectID` in the `OUT` parameter which can hold only one value. Yet you limit the query to 20 rows.

If you want to return max 20 rows, return the rows as a result set (leave out the out parameter and the `INTO objid`), or limit the rows to just one row.